# How to handle Empty List- multiple page web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the question and answer section from Lazada through web scraping, however I am having issue when some of the pages doesn't have any question/answer. My code returns nothing when i run it for multiple web pages but works only for one page that have question and answer.

How do i make the code continue reading the rest of web pages though the first page have no question?

I have tried adding if else statement in my code as shown below.

```
 import bleach
 import csv
 import datetime
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['url1','url2','url3']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 print ("Date data being pulled:")
 print str(now)
 print ("")

 nameList = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"qna-content"})

for name in nameList:
    if nameList == None:
       print('None')
    else:
       print(name.get_text())
       continue
```

my expected output will be something like as shown below :

> None --> *output from url1*
> None --> *output from url2*
> can choose huzelnut?
> Hi Dear Customer , for the latest expiry date its on 2019 , and we will make  sure the expiry date is still more than 6 months.--> *output from url3*

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: did you get an error message?

Comment: `nameList` will never be None because `findAll` always returns a list - an empty list if it finds nothing. Besides it doesn't make sense to check if `nameList` is None while iterating. Also it seems your code is not indented properly; it only selects items from the last URL.

Comment: @ewwink i didnt get any error message, it just returns nothing.

Comment: @t.m.adam yes u are right, i have made some changes through some reading to understand better and manage to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have wrong syntax, put `if nameList == None:` outside the loop, also you need to fix the indentation.

```
urls = ['url1','url2','url3']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print ("Date data being pulled:")
    print str(now)
    print ("")

    nameList = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"qna-content"})
    if nameList == None:
        print(url, 'None')
        continue # skip this URL

    for name in nameList:
        print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: you're welcome, if solved please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes to the logic of the code and manage to print the record for now, since I am still learning, hope to get sharing for others as well if you have alternative/better solution.

```
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = ['url1','url2','url3']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Date data being pulled:")
print str(now)
print ("")

qna = []
qna = soup.findAll("div", class_= "qna-content")

for qnaqna in qna:
     if not qnaqna:
        print('List is empty')
     else:
        print(qnaqna.get_text())
        continue
```

Comment: it will only  process the content for `url3`, see my answer for fix